Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkcalendar' Docker
Подскажите пожалуйста, при запуске образа из контейнера выскакивает ошибка:
from tkcalendar import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkcalendar'
Вот код Docker:
FROM python:3.8

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install tkcalendar

CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как поступить, при обычном запуске все работает. Добавил установку библиотеки tkcalendar, проблема не исчезла.

Очевидно, установить tkcalendar

@andreymal, в DockerFile?

Графическое приложение внутри докер контейнера - это конечно интересно. С большой вероятностью вообще не заработает, ни с календарем, ни без него. Но все равно попробуйте минимальное tkinter приложение (без календаря) создать и запустить в докере.

@insolor, в новом приложении у меня такая ошибка: "no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable"

@Anton ну вот вам приложение и говорит, что экрана нет. Я не очень в курсе, можно ли например под linux сервер экрана (xorg) внутрь докер контейнера пробросить, но это в любом случае попахивает каким-то извращением.

@insolor, понял, спасибо, с докером вот буквально недавно начал разбираться
